Is the Gustin Jeans company legit?
From their website...

Step 1 Back a campaign. We’ll collect your credit card at checkout,
but won’t charge you until production begins on your item. You can
make changes or cancel any time before this.
Step 2 Production begins once an item reaches 100% funding. We’ll let
you know when this happens, but most campaigns reach full funding
within 2 weeks.
Step 3 Your item will ship directly to you once production is
complete. We’ll help you keep tabs on the progress of your item as it
moves through all the steps of production.

I find it a bit dubious to store your credit card details and charge them at a later time. Where are the credit card details being stored so they can be charged at a later time? Does a credit card provider offer these types of delayed charges? It is the first time I have seen it.

You've never booked a hotel before?

@keshlam that is a nice answer in the comments you got there. If you can post it as an answer I would upvote it.

Any site with subscription services that auto-renew stores credit card details so they can charge it at renewal time.

You have three risks:

The product doesn't meet your needs and you might only end up with store credit that you will never use.
The whole thing is a scam.
The place is legit but they are so sloppy with securing their customer information, that you have to do with fraudulent charges or identity theft.

The first one is on you to decide how to handle that risk.
The scam part is handled the same way that you decide how to use a website you have never encountered before. Find other trusted places that have reviewed their products and services. Don't trust only the information on their website.
Sloppy security can be mitigated by using a single use card to make a purchase. Some cards have this service. It can be one number that can be used multiple times by a single vendor, or a number that can be used exactly once.
The twist is that you don't know if the "card" will be charged tomorrow or after the deadline for each campaign. I looked on their website and saw that on 11 November 2024 one of their new campaigns will expire in February 2025. So in about 90 days. They then need 6 to 8 weeks to produce the item and start shipping. Make sure the expiration on the "card" works for that timeline.

I find it a bit dubious to store your credit card details and charge
them at a later time. Where are the credit card details being stored
so they can be charged at a later time? Does a credit card provider
offer these types of delayed charges? It is the first time I have seen
it.

Many vendors do this. Hotels where you make the reservation months before you will use the room, do this all the time. So do car rental companies. I know that season tickets for a professional team are spread over multiple payments.
In many jurisdictions the government limits the companies ability to charge a card before the item is shipped. So it can be days, weeks or months before the card is charged.
These businesses validate your card information; then only store your customer info, shipping information, and a subset of your card details and a validation number they received via the credit card network.

To try to find out if the company is legit, websearch for how long they have existed, how long their website has existed and how it is administered, trustworthy reviews... We have shown how to do some of that in other "is this company legitimate" questions, if anything looks suspicious, go elsewhere.
And remember that sometimes company names get sold, or somebody takes over a company, and it's reputation changes

Any organization that charges credit cards is required to be compliant with the Payment Card Industry Data Security Standards (PCI DSS). These are a number of standards specifying how they process and store the data securely.
Most small vendors don't implement this themselves, as the requirements are quite involved and require extensive security expertise. Instead, they outsource card handling to third party payment processors (e.g. Stripe, PayPal, CyberSource).
However, this assumes the service is legitimate. A scam site has no reason to follow the rules. As others said, you need to do some background research to find out if this particular site actually does what they say.

PCI is worldwide not just US; in fact JCB was among its founders

The standard may be worldwide, but legislation requiring its use presumably depends on the country.

No legislation is involved; the PCI rules are imposed by the card associations by contract, either directly or via acquirers and issuers. See e.g. Visa at https://corporate.visa.com/en/resources/security-compliance.html

Thanks, I've removed the US reference.
